# 24hr & uiDatePicker

Tags: iphone, nsdate, uidatepicker

I need the time from my uiDatePicker to be in 24hr format, I understand you can't force this mode if the device is set to display AM/PM?
If thats the case, how can I detect the device is in 24hr mode (or not) so I can add 12 to my PM times?
Many thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wel you can, you need to set the local:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"NL"];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
[locale release], locale = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks rckoenes, is the "NL" significant? are we just using it temporarily to force the 24hr mode?

Comment: No, you can use UK, it just that I live it the Netherlands. It's just important that you give the formatter a local, then you can use any dat format.

Comment: That's just the Dutch locale. You can change this to whichever you require, or check the NSLocale class reference to be able to output a list of all available locales on device.

Comment: So simply doing this will force the uiDatePicker to always display a 24hr format, and/or make my hours from:[formatter setDateFormat:@"H"] be in 24hr format?;

Comment: Set the date format to 'H' with a local will display 24 hour, setting it to 'H' without the lcoal iOS will in some cases add AM/PM. If you set it to 'h' it will display 12 hours with out AM/PM. 'a' format will display AM/PM.