# Is there anyway to hide the 24hrs format in UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepickermodetime

I am  doing the application with `UIDatePicker` for time format. It is working in 12hrs format, If i change the iPhone date/time to 24hrs format, I need to display only 12hrs format, not the 24hrs format.

Is there anyway to disable the 24hrs format?

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11151187/1153630

Comment: but i want to disable the 24hrs format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code for 12 hour format

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"US"];
[self.datePicker setLocale:locale];
```

Use this code for 24 hour format

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"NL"];
[self.datePicker setLocale:locale];
```

Comment: @user2384583 this will show 12hrs format always. have you tried ?

Comment: if i change the iphone date/time to 24hrs format, it doesnot show the 12hrs format.

Comment: @user2384583 ur wc :)