# localizing + customizing the date format of a UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, localization, uidatepicker

I need to customize and localize the date format of a `UIDatePicker`'s `DateAndTime` mode, so that it will display the date numbers in `Arabic` language plus time in 24 hours format and in Arabic numbers too.

the equivalent row in English would be: `2017 11 15 17:00`

I've tried all the solutions proposed on SO from changing the locale to changing device language but to no avail.

Comment: So, do you want to let the date picker do be displayed in Arabic language?

Comment: yes and the time in 24 hours format

Comment: Can you test the same on device? It might be a bug in simulator.

Comment: I don't use simulator

Answer (score 4):

Let's breaking it down:

- For displaying the content of the date picker to be in *Arabic language* you'd need to set it your desired [`locale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/1615995-locale):

> The locale used by the date picker.

- For changing the format of the date picker, well... it depends on the used locale; As mentioned in the [UIDatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/locale) - Internationalization:

> Date pickers handle their own internationalization; the only thing you
>   need to do is specify the appropriate locale. You can choose a
>   specific locale for your date picker to appear in by setting the
>   Locale (locale) field in Attributes Inspector. This changes the
>   language that the date picker uses for display, **but also the format of**
>   **the date and time (for example, certain locales present days before
>   month names, or prefer a 24-hour clock over a 12-hour clock)**...

which means that setting the desired locale for changing the language also affects the format date of the date picker.

Roughly speaking, setting **both** language and format is unavailable for your case, you should choose the desired language or the desired date format.

However, applying the first point (changing the date picker locale):

```
datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "ar")
```

should leads to the following output:

[image]

Also, the following question:

[Show Time in 12 and 24 hour format in UIDatePicker on the basis of app settings not on device Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151187/show-time-in-12-and-24-hour-format-in-uidatepicker-on-the-basis-of-app-settings)

is also related to changing the date picker format.

Comment: Glad to help :) once you make sure that the answer is the right one, please accept it (green tick). FYI, accepting an answer leads to: - gives the answerer +15 reputation points. - gives you (asker) +2 reputation points. - And the most important thing, it gives an indication that this answer is the solution for such an issue for viewers.