# how to custom language to display in dateTimePicker

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, datetimepicker

Currently the language of the application is English, the device language is Vietnamese, I have set the locale is "en_US" but the title of the time still shows Vietnamese, anyone know how to solve it? here is the result (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Po0q.png)

i tried this way, but not work:

```
    var identifier = "vi_VN"
    let languageCode = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Internationalization")
    if languageCode != "vi" {
        identifier = "en_US"
    }
    let locale = Locale.init(identifier: identifier)
    datePicker.locale = locale
```

Comment: Do you update the language code in the UserDefaults when you change the language to English ?

Comment: Of course yes, even if I try hard code like this it doesn't work: let locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_US")

Comment: I believe this is a bug in UIDatePicker.

Comment: you can try the following link it helped me .Link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47049344/localizing-customizing-the-date-format-of-a-uidatepicker