# 24h UIDatePicker does not offer 24 hours in certain circumstances

Tags: ios, iphone, uidatepicker, ios14

In my app, users can pick a "duration". I am using a `UIDatePicker` with `datePickerMode` set to `time` for this.

- In order to pick 0-24h, I set the date picker `locale` to e.g. `NL` like [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15105900/3585218).
- Because I want to show the picker in a list, I use `compact` for the `preferredDatePickerStyle`
- In order to make it easier for the user to pick a duration, I set `minuteInterval` to `5`

Now, when using this on a device that has 12h time display in the iOS settings, this causes the expanded date picker to only offer hours from 1-12, instead of 0-23.

Interestingly, this problem does not occur when the device is set to 24h time display or I am using any other value for the `minuteInterval` (e.g. `10`) or I am using a different `preferredDatePickerStyle` (e.g. `inline`)

Is this an iOS bug and is there any workaround?

Comment: Are you sure you have set the picker style to compact?  If you do then you will get a runtime exception stating that compact style is not supported with count down timer mode.  Using the `.automatic` style works correctly for me on a device with 12 hour time preference (without needing to change the locale of the picker)

Comment: I have set the datePickerMode to "time", not "countdown". When using "automatic" style, the pickers displays as "compact" and the problem is happening, just like when I set it to "compact" explicitly.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, although forcing 24 hour time through a locale is a bit of a hack anyway.

Comment: Agreed that it is hacky, but it worked pretty well, expect in this specific configuration with the minuteInterval set to 5