# Cannot change the 24-hour/12-hour format for UIDatePicker on iOS 16.5.1

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, ios16

I was use the UIDatePicker on iOS with following snipe to show 24-hour format (override user's setting) and it works fine until iOS16.5.1

```
    myDatePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
```

why I used this? it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151187/show-time-in-12-and-24-hour-format-in-uidatepicker-on-the-basis-of-app-settings)

I tried the hourCycle property (introducing on iOS 16) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75611144)
but no luck.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe unrelated but replace the old NSLocale with Locale instead, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47670687/9223839) from the same question.

Comment: Try again, that won’t compile.

Comment: yeah, I didn't update the parameter name, updated again